# How to set the default store image in Demandware

Tags: demandware

In Demandware, when a store has been added to the system, the default store image appears broken. I have heard that there is a way to upload a default image so that this is used as the default.

Can someone please point me in the direction of either documentation on the topic or let me know how this can be done.

Thanks in advance, Tristam.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `the default store image`? Which resource are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not about the actual Store object but it's about the product images. Since there's no "default store image" in Demandware, this is the most reasonable deduction imho.

[image: large]
[image: medium]
[image: small]

So, if you need to show a default image, which is above, you need to is using an if condition in your template:

```
<isset name="Product" value="${pdict.Product}" scope="page" />

<!-- stuff -->

<isif condition="${!empty(Product.getImage('hi-res', 0))}">
    <isset name="imageURL" value="${Product.getImage('hi-res', 0).getURL()}" scope="page" />
<iselse/>
    <isset name="imageURL" value="${dw.web.URLUtils.staticURL('/images/noimagelarge.png')}" scope="page" />
</isif>

<!-- stuff -->

<img src="${imageURL.toString()}" alt="Product image or default image" />
```

---

You can also check out `/app_storefront_core/cartridge/templates/default/product/components/productimages.isml` file for the usage. Do not forget to adjust your sizes (`hi-res` and `noimagelarge`) according to your settings.

Answer (score 0):

If the image of a store is broken in the frontend it is likely that you do have the image attribute set but the image is not uploaded (to the right location) and thus you end up with a reference that cannot be resolved.